# Seeking simple circuit for converting 5vdc to ~15vac

Tags: ac, inverter, 5v

I picked up some sample smart materials because I have a small project that I want to put 'magic glass' on the outside of so to speak.

I picked up a couple of different sample pieces from a couple different sources to try and one came with a AC adapter/converter to drive the 'clearing' of the smart film, the other came with a small battery operated unit.

Either one seems to clear the material, but throwing the testors on them produced different results.

The AC version (110vac US plug) seems to output ~17vac @ 60Hz. It also seems to clear the film a little better.
The DC version (two AA batteries at 3VDC) outputs ~7.5vac @ 500Hz.

I'm not sure if this smart film needs specific frequencies or not, but this was a purchase off banggood of just a couple small sample pieces about 10cmx15cm each.

My project uses primarily 5vdc with access to low-current 3.3v sources. But I'm guessing this thing would draw too much current (for my 3.3v using the existing driver board) to clear all four panes even after I cut them down to fit inside the project.

So I'm guessing I need something that will generate an AC voltage in the 15v range somewhere between 50-500Hz to drive this thing but I know nothing about building oscillators or inverters. I would also prefer something that could run straight off a 5v source.

(I'm running out of room to put new DiY components. (I'm already stuffing a few props, a servo, a stepper motor, at least 25 LEDs, an i2c PWM board, ultrasonic vaporizor, and a a Raspberry Pi with a ReSpeaker shield a pair of speakers somehow inside of a 10"x6"x6" brass lantern! The smaller/simpler the circuit the better)

Any help is appreciated.

--EDIT 1--
the 110vac which outputs 17vac @ 60Hz is only about 1.4ma
The 3VDC which outputs 7.5vac @ 500Hz is 7ma

Comment: Can you measure either the capacitance of the film **or** the AC current at both 50 Hz and 500 Hz? Please add that information to your original question.

Comment: try running the DC version that you have from 5V

Comment: I recall this diffused film becomes clear with 60Vac at line frequency in < 1 second. ,  frequency is not critical but draws more power with higher f.,

Comment: @DwayneReid I think my meter will do current on AC as well as DC but I'll have to rig up something as it requires a through-connection in-line and the wires/connectors are soldered onto this thing. I have extra connectors but no hall-effect non-intrusive testing gear. I'll see if I can rig something up tomorrow to test the current and update the post.

Comment: a royer inverter is simple.  finding the right transformer to build one may be more difficult.

Comment: current was less than I expected (on the output) - I'd have to do a lot more finaggling with wiring if you want input current

Comment: @DwayneReid I managed to find some jumpers to measure the current and added it to the post. I'm also reading 250nf when I connect the material to my multi-tester.

Comment: @Jasen that's how I let the magic smoke out ;)

Comment: depending on which part smoked you may be able replace it with a similar part.

Comment: @Jasen that's what i was thinking. If not replacing the parts, at least scavenging some of them off the old one. I have 4 of them though because I bought a piece for each face of the lantern. Technically I bought 5 because I was hoping I could bend the first one to cover the three back faces with a single piece. Hint: Don't try to bend smart material.

Comment: 9 months on: What did you end up doing that worked? || I'm unaware of this material - what does it do and what is it used for?

Comment: I actually had to set the project aside because things got crazy at work. It's built to do just what I bought it for- to go semi-opaque when hit with an oscillating current. Automatic frosting-unfrosting glass.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the AC current required by film, you **MAY** be able to use a MAX232 RS-232 driver chip to give you almost 20 Vp-p on the film. Initially, use a CMOS 555 timer chip as an oscillator. This will let you prove whether the RS-232 has sufficient drive.

If in fact the MAX-232 does work, you can probably persuade the MAX-232 to also be the oscillator. But no need to spend any time on that until you know that the MAX-232 will drive the film.

Comment: I swear I had found a circuit at one point because I ordered some op-amps for some reason and thought it was for that in case I needed it. I'm wondering if maybe a small neon driver may work also as there are some already built for USB.

Comment: although now that I think of it, the op-amps were ordered in case I needed to make a circuit for the vaporizer.